# Calculating x% faster than y?

Tags: physics, percentages, programming

I'm working on an app as a little side project, I can handle the code no problem but I can't get my head around some (fairly basic) math right now.

So, I need a formula, please.

The easiest way I can illustrate my problem is to give an example:

A spell has a cast speed of 0.50 seconds, if I apply an x% cast time buff what is its new speed?

i.e It's base cast time is 0.5s and currently its cast time is +144%

Again, I need a general formula where I can plug in both base times and the % speed increase.

Thanks!

Edit: I made a cardinal error in my first post in not posing the problem properly. Part of my app provides a calculation function for a certain game. The game itself tells you a spells base cast time and in another portion of the game you can see any buffs applied to the spell. The way the game expresses is it is at 200% cast time the spell casts twice as fast. So for a 0.5s spell the cooldown is 0.25 seconds, at 400% it's 0.125s and so on... so a 5000% bonus means you are casting 50x faster. I'm having problems when then numbers are a bit more complicated like 144% etc...

I know this is a strange way of representing things but that's how the game does it and part of my app should show the user what their actual cast time is given the bonuses.

So the spell (in game) is represented as a base *time* but the buffs are represented as a % increase in *speed*. - That's what's making my head hurt.

Comment: What is "an x% cast time buff"?

Comment: I assume that you are referring to an *increased* amount of cast time...  If the original casting speed is $y$ and you are *increasing* the amount of time by $x\%$, then the new casting speed would be $y\times (1+\frac{x}{100})$.  For simple example, if the original casting speed was $2$ seconds and you increase the amount of time spent casting by $50\%$ the new time would be $2\times (1+\frac{50}{100})=3$ seconds.  Now... if you were actually wanting $x$ to be a *decrease* in time... then $144\%$ doesn't make any sense.  You will have finished casting half a second before you even started.

Comment: What is commonly done in games like diablo is for faster-cast-rate (FCR) to be multiplicative rather than additive.  If a single item gives $x\%$ faster-cast-rate and the original cast time was $y$, then the new cast time would be $y\times (1-\frac{x}{100})$.  If you have a second item as well that gives $x_2\%$ faster-cast-rate in addition to the first, then the new speed would be $y\times (1-\frac{x}{100})(1-\frac{x_2}{100})$

Comment: I've edited my question to try to clarify exactly what I mean. Thanks to you both though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate * Time = Distance

1.00 * 0.5 = 0.5

1.44 * T = 0.5

T = 0.5 / 1.44

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I overlooked how simple this is. I guess I didn't consider *distance* as a factor because it's not a literal component here, but the calculation works as far as I can tell. (Bangs self on head). :)

I've upvoted you but I'm new here so it doesn't show up yet.

Answer (score 0):

Percent means literally 'every one-hundred', so if you'd like to say $X$ is $y$ percent of $x$, then you write
$$
X = \frac{xy}{100}
$$

Examples:

(1) $x = 0.5 \ \text{sec}$ and $y = 144$, then $X=1.44x \ \text{sec} = 0.72 \ \text{sec}.$

(2) $x = 0.5 \ \text{sec}$ and $y = 10$, then $X = 0.1x \ \text{sec} = 0.05 \ \text{sec}.$

---

If you would like to be more free with the language and say $X$ is $y$ percent more (or less) than $x$, then you would write
$$
X = x + \frac{xy}{100}
$$

Examples:

(1) $x = 0.5 \ \text{sec}$ and $y = 44$, then $X = x + 0.44x = 0.72 \ \text{sec}.$

(2) $x = 0.5 \ \text{sec}$ and $y = -90$, then $X = x -0.9x = 0.05 \ \text{sec}.$

---

The difference between the two is the language used in expressing $y$, otherwise they are exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edited my question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Ah, then S Spring's answer is just fine.

Comment: Yep. All Good. Thanks to everyone for your help and support.